# Why does my GTFS data contain "invisible" line breaks?

Tags: csv, notepad, gtfs

So I've been looking at a way to import GTFS data into an SQLdb for my application. I found a solution available on [GitHub](https://github.com/OpenTransitTools/gtfsdb/tree/master/gtfsdb).

But, this is written using python. I don't think I can use this directly in my windows application. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

But I have no issues with understanding the logic behind the solution and creating my own 'parser'.

So, I opened the GTFS data file "calendar dates.txt" on Notepad and found its content confusing. It was like:

```
service_id,date,exception_type1,20151012,11,20151111,12,20150822,12,20150829,12.....
```

You can see that its confusing when there are no line breaks.
But I paste the code here to show it to you guys, and it automatically formats to:

```
service_id,date,exception_type
1,20151012,1
1,20151111,1
2,20150822,1
2,20150829,1
2
```

Now it clearly makes sense!! (There are spaces in between for parsing)..

But I don't understand. Is Notepad showing it wrong? How do I see the data "properly" then, in order to write my own parser?

Comment: Ok I tried using Notepad++ https://notepad-plus-plus.org/ and it shows it correctly with proper line breaks. Now my question is, is there an actual 'line break' character between the lines, or do advanced CSV parsers somehow intelligently 'detect/insert' them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all copy your related GTFS(routes,shaps etc) and than paste in an online text editor(for example: http://www.editpad.org/)

And than copy from this online text editor and paste again to your original .txt.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your GTFS data is written with UNIX end-of-line characters (linefeed only) as opposed to MS-DOS/Windows characters (carriage return followed by linefeed). This is [permitted by the GTFS spec](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference?hl=en#file-requirements), which says:

> Each line must end with a CRLF or LF linebreak character.

Most application software available for Windows, including Notepad, recognizes only Windows end-of-line characters and opening a file created on UNIX will show the entire contents as a single line, as you've observed. However, tools like Notepad++ that are meant for developers, as well as most programming libraries (such as those meant to parse CSV files), are usually smart enough to recognize both formats and handle them appropriately.

Wikipedia has more information about [end-of-line representations across operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) if you're interested.

Finally, I'll mention that I've recently posted to Github [my own GTFS-to-SQLite loading tool](https://github.com/simonsouth/gtfs2db), which is written in C and uses [libcsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/) to parse GTFS data. If you're developing in a language lower-level than Python you may find it useful as an example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Simon. I suspected as much. Your C program sounds interesting too. I'll definitely check into it. My question is whether my JavaScript code will detect those line breaks in order to parse it. Even so, how would I actually detect it? Should I look for a "\n"? How would I detect line breaks written in all platforms?

Comment: Well, if the JavaScript library you're using has a `readLine` method or similar, you may find it automatically handles these end-of-line issues for you. If not, and you have to do the parsing yourself, simply end the current line each time either a LF character or CR-LF sequence is encountered. Note the GTFS spec requires you only to handle these two cases.

Comment: Also, a quick Google search turns up a few JavaScript libraries for parsing CSV files. Your best bet may be to start with one of these (which, again, ought to handle all this for you) rather than creating something from scratch.

Comment: Best of luck. And if I've been able to answer your question, I'd be grateful if you marked my answer as accepted.